# minimum height in tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to optimize the code:

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Integer Tree Tree
minHeight Empty = -1
minHeight (Node _ Empty Empty) = 0
minHeight (Node _ l     r    ) = (min (minHeight l) (minHeight r)) + 1
```

My goal is to not calculate the branches whose depth will be higher than the already known one.

Comment: Remark: regardless of the convention you use, if you want to be consistent, `Empty` and `Node _ Empty Empty` should not have the same height.

Comment: @Jubobs yes, edited!

Comment: Can you please edit into the question what you mean by _length_, and _current_ length?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Peano `Nat`s instead of `Integer`s and let laziness do the job:

```
data Nat = S Nat | Z deriving (Eq)

instance Ord Nat where
    min (S n) (S m) = S (min n m)
    min  _     _    = Z

instance Enum Nat where
    fromEnum  Z    = 0
    fromEnum (S n) = fromEnum n + 1

data Tree = Empty | Node Integer Tree Tree

minHeight  Empty        = Z
minHeight (Node _  l r) = S (min (minHeight l) (minHeight r))

tree = Node 0 (Node 1 tree Empty) tree

main = print $ fromEnum $ minHeight tree -- 2
```

Comment: Very nice. Note that calculating `min` directly takes even less code than comparison: `minNat (S m) (S n) = S (minNat m n); minNat _ _ = Z`.

Comment: so basically this solution relies the fact that e.g. `1 <= 1 + abs someComputation` should be able to be evaluated to `True` without evaluating `someComputation`, but that it's only possible if instead of the `1` and `3`, a better representation of naturals were used than `Int`/`Integer` — very nice!

Comment: @dfeuer, moreover `minNat n Z` is `Z`, while `min n Z` (where `min` is defined via `(<=)`) doesn't compute. So my version doesn't work for `tree = Node 0 tree (Node 1 tree Empty)`, while your works. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't see why your definition would fail there, actually.

Comment: @dfeuer, it [fails](http://ideone.com/0xFaoS). I thought a bit more, and I don't know why it fails.

Comment: If `n` is bottom/stuck, then `minNat n Z` will be too because pattern matching works from left to right.

Comment: @dfeuer, yes, I always forget that.

Comment: @dfeuer, OK, I see, why your definition works, while my doesn't. It's because yours is productive: `min (S n) (S m)` immediately reduces to `S ...`, while with `(<=)` you have an infinite chain like this: `if (if (if ... <= Z then ... else Z) <= Z then ... else Z) <= Z then ... else Z)`.

Comment: Yes, mine can deal with trees with infinite minimum depth, making use of the fact that `Nat` is actually more like the one-point compactification of the naturals than like the naturals proper.

Answer (score 2):

You want to count depth from top and use returned values of minHeight to bound the other calls.

```
minHeight :: Integer -> (Maybe Integer) -> Tree -> Integer
minHeight depth bound tree = ...
```

Initially pass in 0 as depth and`Nothing` as bound (aka `Infinity`), at leaves return the smaller of `depth` and `bound`, otherwise see if you have a finite bound (`Just b`) and compare it to current `depth`.

```
case b of
    Just min -> if min <= depth then return min else RECURSION
    otherwise -> RECURSION
```

Whenever you compute some `minHeight` in recursion, combine its result with the current `bound`.

```
minHeight d min (Node _ t1 t2) =
    let min1 = Just (minHeight (d + 1) min t1) in
        (minHeight (d + 1) min1 t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, which doesn't calculate the branches, whose depth will be higher then the already known one:

```
data Tree = Empty | Node Integer Tree Tree

minHeight :: Tree -> Int
minHeight =
  loop Nothing 0
  where
    loop defaultDepth depth tree =
      case defaultDepth of
        Just x | x <= depth ->
          x
        _ ->
          case tree of
            Empty -> depth
            Node _ left right ->
              loop (Just (loop defaultDepth (succ depth) left)) (succ depth) right
```